# What to do when I see crashes of my app inside iOS Analytics?

Tags: ios, crash, analytics

I suppose this is stupid question but what to do when I see crashes of my iOS app inside **Apple App Analytics**?

Is there a way to obtain crash report to see what goes wrong?

Comment: Use should consider using crash reporting tools like crashlytics or crittercism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in iTunes connect go to MyApps-> select your app-> select the last version -> at the bottom of page you will find `Additional Information` -> crash reports

Comment: I see this but it looks somehow outdated - first it has iOS version up to 8.2? Second all tabs point that *too few reports have been submitted*. I have 2 crashes for sure?